# drawing a bunch of images on the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have 8 images  with a size of 80 KB, I draw them on the canvas using a loop. Sometimes not all of them are drawn. What could be the reason?

too much work for the ctx?

```
// img[] containing single image.src

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var width = 10;
var height = 10;

for( var i = 0; i< 8 ; i++){

 ctx.drawImage(img[i], x + 10 * i, y + 10 * i, width, height);

}
```

Comment: Does this run when the page loads? You need to ensure that the images are loaded before drawing them onto the canvas.

Comment: can you post all of your code?

Comment: to make your question answerable you need to provide a sample code. you can use jsfiddle for example. what you have gives no information. my wild guess is that you have to wait for the images to finish loading before drawing them.

Comment: I expect you to not see anything but the last drawn image because you never change the destination coordinates.

Comment: It is a part of of huge app, sorry for posting pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

Are you updating `x`, `y`, `position`, and `height`? If not, you may be drawing over the images, which would make it look like some aren't showing up.  However, you should post more info, such as how many images are showing up, the whole function you are using to draw the images with, and a screenshot of what your attempt looks like.  That way, we can help you more effectively

Comment: the above is not an answer. it is a comment.

Comment: Based on how you updated it, I would say that your problem is that you arent updating your variables as you change images. For each image, you are going to have `x = 0`, `y = 0`, `width = 10`, and `height = 10`.  You should make an `image` object that holds each images coordinates and reference them as you loop through your array. Ex. `ctx.drawImage(img[i], img[i].x, img[i].y, img[i].width, img[i].height)`

Comment: @akonsu, its the closest thing to an answer that I could make it.  I dont have enough rep to comment on other peoples posts and I'm just trying to help this guy out

Answer (score 0):

make sure the images are loaded. something like this (not tested):

```
var urls = [...];

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    var image = new Image();

    image.src = urls[i];
    image.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(this, ..., ..., this.width, this.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a onload function , afterwards the array is filled with the img.src

Comment: ok. sorry. I have no more ideas. I need to see the code to get more ideas. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a mistake on my server, sorry guys.